# Handling data loss in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am doing some research on how to prevent data loss during migration and stumbled upon Liquibase.

How does Liquibase handle data loss?

Is there any loss of data when we use Liquibase in data migration? (Drop of Index/Column etc)

Thanks

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what Liquibase does. It runs SQL statements that **you** specify in a controlled manner. If you tell it to drop a column, then yes you lose data because the column and its data is gone. What kind of magic do you expect that tool to do?

Comment: If you want magic like that, you might look at Datical DB, a commercial offering that uses Liquibase at its core. Datical DB adds things like forecast (to let you know if you are about to lose data) and a rules engine (to actually prevent losing data). Disclaimer: I work for Datical.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the goal of Liquibase, which is designed to handle schema lifecycle for an application: create table, index, columns, drop table, etc (DDL)
Liquibase deals with data only for initialization or configuration (best practice).

If you want to migrate data from one database to another you can use the editor tools to export/import (if target schema is the same).
Otherwise, you can use ETL tools like Talend for example.
AWS also offer tools to do so in their cloud environment.